# Disabling warning is good or bad approach in React Native

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';

useEffect(() => {
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(['VirtualizedLists should never be nested']);
}, [])
```

like Above code we disable the warning.

Comment: This is a bad practice.
You should use something like SectionList

Answer (score 0):

It's a good approach when it's a warning that it's caused by a thing that it's not under your control, like a warning from a lib. But when it's a thing that you can fix, that it's caused because of a error of yours, it's not a good pratice.
This warning that it's appearing to you `VirtualizedLists should never be nested` it's caused by you, it's a good pratice to fix and don't suppress the warning.